# ibtool can't build - The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I get the following error when building my project in Xcode 7 beta 5:

```
Summary:
My project won't build, the following error is given:
LinkStoryboards
    cd /Users/lewis/Projects/MyApp/code/ios9
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --module MyApp --target-device iphone --minimum-deployment-target 8.0 --output-format human-readable-text --link /Users/lewis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awistawhhrjdspbponhiluccszrg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app /Users/lewis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awistawhhrjdspbponhiluccszrg/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Storyboard\ ios7.storyboardc /Users/lewis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awistawhhrjdspbponhiluccszrg/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Settings.storyboardc /Users/lewis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awistawhhrjdspbponhiluccszrg/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/TrackIt.storyboardc /Users/lewis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awistawhhrjdspbponhiluccszrg/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/UserList.storyboardc /Users/lewis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awistawhhrjdspbponhiluccszrg/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Migration.storyboardc /Users/lewis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awistawhhrjdspbponhiluccszrg/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Intro.storyboardc /Users/lewis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awistawhhrjdspbponhiluccszrg/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/YourMyApp.storyboardc /Users/lewis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-awistawhhrjdspbponhiluccszrg/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/AddMeasurements.storyboardc


/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
: error: The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
    Failure Reason: The file doesn’t exist.
    Underlying Errors:
        Description: The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory
        Failure Reason: No such file or directory
```

I've tried the following based on advice from other SO questions:

- Clean build folder
- Delete derived data
- Checked the Info.plist exists in project folder
- Checked file is expected in Build Settings > Packaging > Info.plist file
- Copying Info.plist into the the folders mentioned in the ibtool command
- Adding the Info.plist to the Copy Bundle Resources section of Build Phases
- Opening all of the Storyboard files in Xcode and checking they open and don't show any errors
- Reinstalling Xcode Beta
- Restarting machine (Mac OS 10.10.5)

I've filed a radar (because the project builds fine on Xcode 6), but it feels like there's more I could do to diagnose this myself. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: same problem here... i use different plist for some schemes.

Comment: I had a different plist for each scheme, but changed down to just one to try and get one scheme to build. no joy :(

Comment: Same Problem over here .. i opened my project in new Xcode Beta, did a lot of work on some files. Opened it up in the last public GM version to prepare a release and then i also got that ibtool error. Nothing worked so far ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is, you have a storyboard that is targeted lower than the target. Set the target of the storyboard to be higher (or better, set it to be the same as deployment target), and it will compile.

Comment: I set all the storyboards to be same as deployment target and BOOM! it worked! Thanks. I'll update the Radar.

Answer (score -1):

Same issue on Xcode 7 Beta 5, I fixed this by creating a new storyboard, and copying all objects from old storyboard to new one.

Comment: new beta is out and still no joy and no word on my radar. Will try this tomorrow, thanks

Comment: the accepted answer makes sense for this, because recreating your storyboard would update the target version.